# The `]` and `}` are not metacharacters in Regex whereas ')' is

Tags: regex

In [Regular Expressions Quick Start](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html), it states

> Twelve characters have special meanings in regular expressions: the backslash \, the caret ^, the dollar sign $, the period or dot ., the vertical bar or pipe symbol |, the question mark ?, the asterisk or star *, the plus sign +, the opening parenthesis (, the closing parenthesis ), the opening square bracket [, and the opening curly brace {. These special characters are often called "metacharacters". Most of them are errors when used alone.

In its specification, `()`, `[`,`{` are metacharacters whereas 'closing sqare bracket' and 'closing curly brace' are not.

Obviously,'[' and '{' unable to take an effect individually just like opening parenthesis `(` should partners ')'.

What's the reason that causes ']' and `}` failing to be selected?

Comment: I think all this is saying is that `/[/` is always an error but `/]/` might not.

Comment: The main reason, I suppose, is that round brackets are widely used for many kind of groups and constructions eventually nested (capturing, non-capturing, named groups, atomic groups, lookarounds, conditional...) when square brackets are only used for character classes and curly brackets for quantifiers. With these brackets, you can easily deduce if they are literal characters or not with the context. But doing the same with round brackets looks like a nightmare. A parse error is more useful to inform that round brackets aren't balanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a good reason why unmatched `]` and `}` should be literals and `)` shouldn't.

The reason `]` and `}` are often (but not always) interpreted as literals when they don't come in pairs, and `)` isn't, is probably a combination of "historical" and "because parentheses nest". (And as a consequence of both, as Casimir et Hippolyte pointed out, because parentheses are used to mean a bunch of things related to grouping, lookarounds, etc.)

In [academia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language#Formal_definition), regexes are simplified down to `|` (alternation), concatenation and `*` ([Kleene-star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star)), and parentheses are the first convenience syntax. If you were to make a recursive descent parser recognize `[` as entering a state where the syntax is slightly different, and `]` means leaving that state again, then recognizing `]` outside of that state as being an error would not be a direct side-effect of recognizing `[`. So if the bug doesn't blow up, it's a feature!

Parentheses are unlike this: Since the regex parser must keep track of which level they're nested, recognizing unmatched `)`s in its primary state is a required part of such a parser, and giving an error rather than producing a literal `)` is something the writer of such a parser is more inclined to do.

Notice that `(` and `)` can often come unescaped and unmatched inside character groups.